# Gravity Forms: Dynamic creation of fields

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin

I see a lot of discussion about dynamically populating fields, but not much of any about dynamically creating fields. I have what appears to be a simple form. It consists of an arbitrary number of questions with a set of possible choices. For example:

```
Which of the following would you choose?

    o  Choice #1
    o  Choice #2

    +----------+   +----------+  
    |   BACK   |   |   NEXT   |  
    +----------+   +----------+
```

The form would require a radio button to be selected, the NEXT button becomes active and the user proceeds to the next question.

There are dozens of questions with each question on its own page of a multi page form. It's a lot of configuration within Gravity Forms. Since each page will be identical in layout and functionality I am wondering if there is a suggested way of outputting this form dynamically.

Is there a way of creating form fields dynamically from within a hook/action in functions.php?

The reason I am asking is to explore the possibility of wrapping a Gravity Forms shortcode with one that allows configuration of the questions and answers.

Comment: Hi @rwkiii could you share your experience using the answer below? Specifically, were you ask to export your dynamic fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [gform_pre_render](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_pre_render/) filter is called on every form page load. You can manipulate the `$form['fields']` to add/remove/modify the form's fields. This includes adding pages and fields on the fly (pages are just a field with the type "page").

Comment: Would you know if the dynamically added form field data is able to be saved by Gravity Forms as usual so that it can be exported/viewed? I'm glad to hear they can be added on the fly. I wasn't able to find any examples of adding fields nor even confirmation that it could be done. Do you know of any reference for adding fields in PHP?

Comment: It is possible but you would need to develop a system to account for this. Assuming you have the same set of data from which the fields would be generated, you could populate all of the fields into the form prior to export. They would need unique and static field IDs so the data maps correctly.